# In C++, are pointers like cell references in an Excel Worksheet?

Tags: c++, pointers, excel-formula

I'm an average programmer in C++, and usually avoid pointers at all costs. But I have recently started using some APIs, that are just full of them. And honesty, they seem to work a lot better, if I just continue down a similar path, as that intended/implied by the author of the API.

In form and function, but obviously not syntax - Can "Pointers" be looked at as being, "even somewhat", analogous to "Cell References" in Microsoft Excel?

I have several years of experience with Microsoft Excel w/VB. I'm also sort of a "Formula/Reference Junkie", when it comes to using Excel, so this train of thought just makes sense to me. I just want to know if I'm "Pointed" in the right direction.

Thank You!

Comment: I am sorry to say that but if you are confused about pointers you are not an *average* C++ programmer. But keep up ! C++ is a wonderful language that will teach you a lot about computer science.

Comment: @Ugo - It is possible to write useful and efficient code in C++, without ever using a single pointer. It is also possible to mind your own business, if you don't have anything meaningful to share.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A cell reference in Excel is a string that indicates a certain location in a workbook (or, under certain circumstances, another workbook).

A pointer in C++ is a *memory address*. The memory address is a number (nothing more!) that locates a certain spot in virtual RAM.

So yes, they actually are rather similar. I was prepared to rain on your parade by talking about how different the two are. But the analogy works.

When you "dereference" a pointer, you're going to the spot in memory which it indicates. In Excel you don't really "dereference" the cell references. But close enough.

When you say `int y = 4; int* x = &y;`, that's kind of like creating a cell at B1 containing "4", and then another cell that contains "=B1".

Comment: The last sentence in your reply, is what got me to thinking this way in the first place - because I do that ("=B1") all the time. The second sentence in your reply, is sort of my "disambiguation" that prompted my question - A cell reference in Excel, is a number "and letter" (nothing more), that locates a certain location in a worksheet. << there's my analogy. I like your answer, Thanks!

Comment: Consider the cell reference a named reference. In the Excel code there is most likely a function that converts this to an actual cell reference, possible signature: `Cell * locateRef( char const * ref )`. This named reference is in the spreadsheet domain, whereas the pointer reference is in the memory domain, but they both refer to the same thing.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y, I didn't mean it quite so literally, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

There are several analogies that spring to mind, but, the classic one when I first learnt computer programming was mail boxes in the mail room. Imagine mail boxes labelled, Tom, Dick and Harry.

- In Tom's mail box, place an envelope that says there's a clue in Dick's mail box
- In Dick's mail box, place an envelope that says the treasure is in Harry's mail box
- In Harry's mail box, you put $100 dollars! Yippee!

In computer programming, Tom, Dick and Harry are all memory addresses. The first two contain pointers, the third, contains a numerical value. Opening the envelope in Tom or Dick's mailboxes are like dereferencing pointers.

We write this:

```
int harry = 100;
int *dick = &harry;
int **tom = &dick;
```

So, **tom == *dick == harry == 100.
Whilst tom is a pointer to a pointer to harry.
And dick is a pointer to harry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a reasonable analogy.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is nothing but an *address of a memory* that holds something (or nothing).

Regardless whether the cell actually contains any data, it's address, can be thought of a as a pointer to the cell.

Note that the cell itself is not a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

No, not really. Pointers can be indexed, and they can also be invalid, and I believe that neither of those things is true for Excel cells.

Comment: Both are true in Excel.
You can index a range of cells, or even by the contents of a single cell.
Invalid cells references are displayed as errors - #VALUE!, #DATA!, etc.